# Program keep looping in while loop with 3 variable C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, boolean

I keep getting an infinite loop on this while loop and can't figure it out what's going wrong. I copy my code and put it below.

Comment: Suggest adding `-Wshadow` to your gcc/clang compile string to catch shadowed variables. If using another compiler, check the documentation and enable the option to detect shadowed variables.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the variables

```
// set to false at the begining at the loop
bool upper = false;                                             
bool lower = false;
bool num = false;
```

inside the loop. These are different variables than those that are declared outside the loop. The conditional in the `while` statement uses the variables outside the loop, which are never modified. All modifications to these variables change the state of the variables in the block scope only, not the variables outside the loop.

Remove the `bool` from the above lines to fix the problem.

```
// set to false at the begining at the loop
upper = false;                                             
lower = false;
num = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see many issues in your code.

Primo, and this is the reason why you came, you should assign value to your booleans in your loop without redeclaring them:

```cpp
bool upper = false;     // <- remove bool type inside loop                                        
bool lower = false;
bool num = false;
```

About design: you write SIZE in uppercase. As you should know, you write variable in uppercase <s>if someone stole the election from you</s> if your variable is a preprocessor directive (a macro, #define) and if it is a constexpr. Here your size vary so it should be lowercase. Also we usually call it `len` which is shorten for length, when talking about the length of a string.

Then the following could be rewritten as a do while (this is a minor point):

```
        getline(cin, password);                                                 //store input into string

        SIZE = password.length();                                               //getting size of the string

        while(SIZE < 6)                                                         //check if it's more than 6 char
        {                                                                       //loop til it's
            cout << "Need more than 6 character in password" << endl;
            getline(cin, password);
            SIZE = password.length();
        }
```

Finally you do not need so many branching instructions (if):

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
     upper |= isupper(password[i]);  //check for uppercase char
     lower |= islower(password[i]);  //check for lowercase char
     num |= isdigit(password[i]);      //check for digit
}
```

It will set the boolean flags accordingly.